# Не появляется прерывистое подчеркивание

Tags: html, css

Есть такие стили ссылок:

```
a:link{
    color: #b21;
    text-decoration: none;
}  
a:visited {
    color: #553322; 
    text-decoration: none;
}  
a:hover {
    color: #bb0000;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #bb0000;
}  
a:active {
    color: #443322;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Но, по неизвестной мне причине, при наведении на ссылку, не появляется прерывистое подчеркивание. В чем может быть ошибка?

P.S. вот сайт, если что: http://vagantsfest.ru/

Comment: Всё работает, прерывистое подчёркивание появляется. Очистите кэш браузера, возможно, из-за этого вы не видите изменения. Так же, в отдельном css-файле нет смысла писать в начала и в конце html-комментарии

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно, все работает)

Comment: Если вы хотите? чтоб ссылки всегда были без подчёркивания, не обязательно писать в каждом псевдоклаcсе text-decoration: none;, достаточно 1 раз написать в :link.